# How to remove an item from array by index in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark-sql, sparse-matrix

I work with Scala and I'd like to remove items from an array by index
Can anybody please assist me?

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;

val sv1 = Seq((1, "Y", 0, (0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5)), 
             (2, "N", 0, (0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6)),
             (3, "N", 0, (0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7)),
             (4, "N", 1, (0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8)),
             (5, "N", 1, (0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9)))
             .toDF("id", "label", "test", "array_features")
.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")  

val nums: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

So I'm expecting to receive 2 columns only (instead of 4). An array of 5*2 without column 1 and 2.

Comment: you want to delete a single item or a list of items?

Comment: I have a list in indexes and I'd like to remove them from the array:
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;

val sv1 = Seq((1, "Y", 0, (0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5)), 
             (2, "N", 0, (0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6)),
             (3, "N", 0, (0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7)),
             (4, "N", 1, (0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8)),
             (5, "N", 1, (0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9)))
             .toDF("id", "label", "test", "array_features")
.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")  

val nums: List[Int] = List(1, 2)